# Writing a law of cosines calculation

Tags: c, excel, math, trigonometry

I'm trying to make a function in C that returns the length of the side of a triangle that is opposite to a given angle, using the Law of cosines.

Now I got the formula to work in excel and it gave the correct results. However when I tried it in C I am getting the wrong results, and I can not work out why.

For the test I have sideA as 21.1, sideB as 19 and the angle between them as 40 degrees. Now the answer should be 14.9 like I get in excel. however in C I'm getting 23.735. Please some one help me work out where I went wrong

```
// Find the length of a side of a triangle that is oppisit a given angle using the Law Of Cosine
// for example using an triangle that is 21.1cm on one side, 19 cm on the other and an angle of 40 degreese inbetween then....
// in excel it worked and the formuler was  =SQRT(POWER(23.1;2)+POWER(19;2)-2*(23.1)*(19)*COS(40*(3.14159/180))) = 14.9 cm
float my_Trig_LawOfCos_OppSideLength(float centerAngle, float sideA, float sideB)
    {
        float sideLengthPow2= (pow(sideA,2) + pow(sideB,2))) - ((2*sideA*sideB)*cos(centerAngle*(3.14159/180));
        float sideLength = sqrt(sideLengthPow2);
        return sideLength;
    }
```

Comment: Your parentheses aren't balanced (my compiler just complained when I copy pasted your sample). So I don't believe this is your actual code.

Comment: [And when I fixed *that* problem I got the result you expected](http://ideone.com/Gd4oqO).

Comment: Note , if code is using `float`, might as well use `float` functions: `sqrtf()`, `cosf()`, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens if you pass the arguments in the wrong order. You put the side length `23.1` in the position of the angle.

```py
def oppside(ang, lA, lB): return (lA**2+lB**2-2*(lA)*(lB)*cos(ang*(pi/180)))**0.5

oppside(40,19,23.1)
>>> 14.905575729577208

oppside(19,23.1,40)
>>> 19.65430416708927

oppside(23.1,19,40)
>>> 23.72490935854042
```

Quite often you can find such errors by producing a minimal executable example that shows the wrong result, because then you would also document the erroneous function call (and perhaps even see it for yourself).